# How to extract next url of base URL from a string in regular expression in php?

Tags: php, regex, routes

For Example :

```
http://www.baseURL.com/sports/what-sports/sportsName-golf/golf/mini-golf/menu
```

or :

```
http://www.baseURL.com/dance/what-dnace/dnaceName-dhupodi/menu
```

I'd like to get:

```
dance
```

OR

```
sports
```

Here is my code :

```
$router->map('GET','/[*:subMenu]/menu','KisorniruTest/index.php','subMenu');
```

By this way i'm getting result but result is either `sports/what-sports/sportsName-golf/golf/mini-golf` or `dance/what-dnace/dnaceName-dhupodi` But I want to pick only `sports` or `dance`. I've done some searching on this, But i didn't get my expected result.

I use this class for routing : http://altorouter.com/

Comment: Have you looked at parse_url at all? It might be a better choice than trying to cobble a regex together.

Comment: Using regular expressions to extract stuff from URLs is rarely a good idea (unless you know what the URL looks like, and you know what you are doing). Parsing the URL into its constituent parts, and then finding the value from there, is a better approach. The `parse_url()` function should get you going, and parsing the path should be relatively easy (paths are separated by the `/` character, `explode()` may be useful).

Answer (score 1):

If i were you i will use a php library to manipulate easily the urls

Like :

http://url.thephpleague.com/3.0/

it did everything that i want for several project.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

> ```
> $url = 'http://www.baseURL.com/dance/what-dnace/dnaceName-dhupodi/menu';
> $a = parse_url($url);
> $u = explode("/",$a['path']);
> print_r($u[1]);
> ```